# Placement of 'always'

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Which of the following is the most appropriate usage

- "You have to be *always* logical in your analysis."
- "You *always* have to be logical in your analysis."
- "You have to be logical in your analysis *always*."

Thanks.

Comment: This question would probably be more appropriate in [ell.se] particularly as it is apparently related to an English examination question (see comments below from OP).

Comment: So what? Why not just answer the obvious questions implicit here? Are all the sentences grammatical? (Yes) Is there any difference between the sentences semantically? (No)  And are these the only places _always_ can appear? (No; there are others as well)

Comment: @TrevorD ELL is the forum for 'speakers of other languages  learning English'. I have spoken and studied English since kinder garden.I am asking the question above to aid my preparation of a certain management entrance exam which tests people on grammatically correct English of Graduation level. So I thought it would not be appropriate for the ELL forum.

Comment: @Suy Your profile gives no relevant info. I assumed from this and your other questions - and from your reference to an examination - that English is not your native language. In fact you'll see that EL&U states that it is "site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."  But in neither case does the description actually match what happens.

Comment: @TrevorD yeah you are basically right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you want to place the emphasis, and that in turn depends on what has gone on before in the text, but the second is the most natural position.

Comment: A rough guide - **guide** , not set of rules - for positioning adverbs - can be found at http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adverb-position.htm . Though there are probably almost as many exceptions as conformities, and the freedom of choice for emphasis Barrie mentions is often a factor.

Comment: So basically all are grammatically correct. Also, why does the second appear most natural to you?

Comment: Another piece of information: The question above has been asked for the purpose of dealing with sentence correction in GMAT and other similar exams.

Comment: The question does ask for the most appropriate usage - not the 'correct **one**' . You could guess that they really mean 'the most natural sounding'. And I'll take the liberty of answering for Barrie - "I've been speaking the language for about 60 years, and it's the way I usually hear / say it." I've given up expecting all of English usage to be logical.

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself, Edwin!

Comment: What is "GMAT"?

Comment: "General M-something A-something Test". Somewhere in the world, it has to be a standard test, for some value of "standard", and this is apparently the kind of question they ask on it.

Comment: gmat is the test for admission to management schools in universities like Harvard, Stanford etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of *the most appropriate*. To me the first two seem to be the same, I'd say there's not much of a difference in meaning. In the first *alway* modifies logical and your analysis, while in the second *always* modifies *have to* and the rest. No difference in meaning, I'd say, unless the context was different.

The last one can be said in situations where you forget *always* and want to add it afterward. A comma before *always* would be good.

Comment: They don't seem identical to me. An analysis comprises many steps. One can be logical at each step (the 1st sentence), but also one can have a logical approach generally (allowing some slack at a step or two) for each analysis (the 2nd S). I'd say the 3rd S covers the 1st and 2nd meaning.